# How do I bind 2 java files so they both open when I run the jar file

Tags: java, eclipse

I think this can be done in eclipse? But how.

Basically what I want is to turn 2 java jars into 1 jar file and when I run it they both run.

Comment: Why do you need to bind them together? One java file only contains one class. If you want to refer to the other class in a jar, it would automatically loaded. You don't need to "bind" them together.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other ways, but one way to do this is by running the second jar file through the first file. You can run the second file as:

```
String cmd = "java -jar "+getClass().getResource("secondFile.jar").getPath().substring(1);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```